# Django InconsistentMigrationHistory on first migration. Can't make migrations after initial migrations

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use a custom user model with my django app.

In settings.py:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'sfauth.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    # These 3 are custom apps in a folder ROOT/api/apps/X (root = where manage.py is)
    'api.apps.sfauth',  # Contains the custom user model
    'api.apps.admin',  # Custom admin site
]
```

apps/admin/admin.py

```py
class SFAdminSite(AdminSite):
    """
    Custom override for Django Admin page
    """
    site_header = ADMIN_HEADER
```

apps/admin/apps.py:

```py
class SFAdminConfig(apps.AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'api.apps.admin.admin.SFAdminSite'
```

I can run the first `makemigrations` just fine.

```
Migrations for 'sfauth':
  api\api\apps\sfauth\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model User
    - Create model APIRequestLog
```

But if I run it again, I get

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency sfauth.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Initial migration works fine

```
manage.py migrate 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, ignition, sessions, sfauth
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sfauth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying authtoken.0001_initial... OK
  Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747... OK
  Applying authtoken.0003_tokenproxy... OK
  Applying ignition.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I run showmigrations, it says all the migrations haven't applied.

```
manage.py showmigrations 
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
authtoken
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20160226_1747
 [ ] 0003_tokenproxy
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sfauth
 [ ] 0001_initial

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried commenting out my custom user model, making the migrations and migrating, then adding it back, which didn't work.

I am ok with recreating the database and losing all data to fix this, but I've tried that as well and it doesn't do anything, since the initial migration works but its making migrations that fails afterwards.

Comment: Please share the two migration files together with the corresponding model.

Answer (score 0):

Remove migrations already created.

Then create migrations for only "sfauth"

```
python manage.py makemigrations sfauth
python manage.py migrate
```

After than create all migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Be sure to keep "__init.py__" file inside migrations folder.

Comment: Even with that, I can't run the first migration.  I get the same `ProgrammingError` shown above.  I also tried it with just `manage.py migrate sfauth`

Comment: you need to delete the database first

Comment: I already deleted it, and still get the error when attempting the first migration.